# Get and Set values in local resource file

Tags: c#

I have put 2 strings in the built-in resource file of my main project (not sure how I define this properly).  How can I access these values?  How would I change them?  The resource is public so that the user can change them.

eg:

```
Project1.Resources.Get("string1").Value();
```

and

```
Project1.Resources.Set("string1") = "whatever";
```

This is pseudo code.

Comment: Resources are meant to be compile-time constant, not changeable by the user ...

Comment: @McGarnagle I was able to do this in VB.Net setting the resources to public allows the user to change the settings, no need for .ini files.

Comment: @user2864613 That's application settings - they're not the same as "general resources", and saving doesn't save back into the executable's resource.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Resources are not intended to be changed at runtime.  You should consider using user settings instead.  For details, see [Using Application Settings and User Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750.aspx) on MSDN.

This will allow you to use the designer to build the settings, and write:

```
string string1 = Properties.Settings.Default.String1;
```

And:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.String1 = "whatever";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get resource by writing the following piece of code

```
    Project1.Resources.String1
```

You can not change it at runtime.